# jQuery - click then show function, then click again and show another function and so on.. Not clicked and show all functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieved something that when I click the paragraph my 1st function will run then click the paragraph again and the 2nd function will run, then click the paragraph again and the 3rd function will run and so on.. Not when I click the paragraph all of the functions will run, I have achieved only up to the 2nd function and now I'm stuck.

Here's the code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jQuery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$().ready(function(){
    $("h1").hide();
    $("h2").hide();
    $("h3").hide();

    function func1(){
        $("h1").show();
    }
    function func2(){
        $("h2").show();
    }

    function func3(){
        $("h3").show();
    }

    function funcme(){
        if($("p").click(func1)){

            $("h1").show();
            $(this).click(func2);
        }

    }
$(this).click(func3);
    $("p").click(funcme);

});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>CLICK ME</p>
<h1>FUNC 1</h1>
<h2>FUNC 2</h1>
<h3>FUNC 3</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An alterantive: On the click, check if h1 is visible, if it is, show h2... etc

Comment: you talk about showing/hiding functions, but you are showing/hiding elements. What do you really what to show/hide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a more elegant solution?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $().ready(function(){
        var counter = 0;

        $('.section').hide();


        $(".func-me").on('click', function (event){
           $('.section').eq(counter).show();
           counter++;
        });
    });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>


    <button class="func-me">CLICK ME</button>
    <p class="section">FUNC 1</p>
    <p class="section">FUNC 2</p>
    <p class="section">FUNC 3</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vnavv1v7/

Comment: That's wrong. `click(){}`  is incorrect, should be `click(function() {});`

Comment: You are right, I was copy pasting and editing, so its a typo., will fix it

Comment: Thanks for the tip sir! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to create a flag? For example, your flag is set in zero. Then you make your first click, change your flag to 1. Then you make the second click, change your flag to 2... and so on...

I don't understand what you need to do in each click.. But I think something like this...

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("h1").hide();
      $("h2").hide();
      $("h3").hide();

      var flag = 0;

      $("p").click(funcme(flag)); 

      function funcme (flag){
          if (flag == 0)
             func1();
          if (flag == 1)
             func2();
          if (flag == 2)
             func3();
          flag++;
      }

      function func1(){
          $("h1").show();
      }

      function func2(){
          $("h2").show();
      }

     function func3(){
         $("h3").show();
     }
  }
</script>
```